# Can't play m3u8 file in VLC or decrypt it with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, m3u8

I have found and downloaded the m3u8 file using the developer tools in Edge. However, it won't play directly in VLC.

I then downloaded all the segments referred to in the m3u8 file as well as the key and put them in the same folder as ffmpeg. The partial contents of the m3u8 file are:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:13
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="keyfile.txt",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000001
#EXTINF:12,
seg-1-z.ts
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="keyfile.txt",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000002
#EXTINF:12,
seg-2-z.ts
...
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="keyfile.txt",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000013E
#EXTINF:8,
seg-318-z.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

The keyfile.txt contents are: eyJwYXNzcGhyYXNlIjoiNjE0YjQ5NTYzYTdlYiIsImNpcGhlcnRleHQiOiJlamZOTWRSZjltY3Z4R1JRTFg2cVMralJJTmZaUGJyMXVyaFhhTVZ1QVptSUpXZVdYMkZLQ0t1Q0ZCYUQwY3FYIiwiaXYiOiIxZTNlNzg3ZjNjYmRlOGViZDdlZTBkNWVhZDA1NmEzNCIsInNhbHQiOiIwNjc3M2I1OWE1Y2IxZjA3ODdkYmEzZTAwYWZmNGIzNyJ9

This is what I get when I run ffmpeg:

```
C:\Test\download>ffmpeg -allowed_extensions ALL -i "play.m3u8" -c copy "test.ts"
ffmpeg version 2021-09-16-git-8f92a1862a-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      57.  5.100 / 57.  5.100
  libavcodec     59.  7.103 / 59.  7.103
  libavformat    59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8.  9.100 /  8.  9.100
  libswscale      6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[hls @ 000001c67608d140] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 000001c67608d140] Opening 'keyfile.txt' for reading
[hls @ 000001c67608d140] Opening 'crypto:seg-1-z.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001c67608d140] Error when loading first segment 'seg-1-z.ts'
play.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Did you check ffmpeg's trac? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8490